# What's the optimal way to show a check mark against four settings with forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a screen that shows four rows: "English", "Romaji", "Kana" and "Kanji".  The user can select one of the four and when selected a check mark will appear next to it.  Currently it's implemented like this (just showing the first two):

```
        englishSide.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                englishImage.IsVisible = true;
                romajiImage.IsVisible = false;
                kanaImage.IsVisible = false;
                kanjiImage.IsVisible = false;
            })
        });

        romajiSide.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            Command = new Command(() =>
            {
                englishImage.IsVisible = false;
                romajiImage.IsVisible = true;
                kanaImage.IsVisible = false;
                kanjiImage.IsVisible = false;
            })
        });
```

As the number of choices increases from 4 to more I can see this would get a lot more complicated. Is there a more optimal way to do this?

For reference here's the Xaml:

```
<TableSection Title="Card Front Side">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="englishSide" Padding="20,0,20,0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="English" XAlign="Center"/>
                            <Image x:Name="englishImage" Source="check.png" 
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="romajiSide" Padding="20,0,20,0"
                                Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label Text="Romaji" XAlign="Center"/>
                            <Image x:Name="romajiImage" Source="check.png" 
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" IsVisible="false" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you would need is a proper viewmodel pattern where the `ListView.ItemsSource` is an `IEnumerable<YourViewModel>`. I use Prism for Xamarin.Forms to facilitate this.

Read more:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

YourViewModel will be the child viewmodel containing all the logic and ecapsulating the business object.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged would be needed
    public MyModel Model {get;set;}

    public bool IsChecked {get;set;}

    public string Image => this.IsChecked? "theImage.jpg" : null;
}
```

Hope that helps.